# How to pass props when a component is passed as a prop of another component?

Tags: react-native, react-props, react-component

I have a component as follows:

```
const ArrowDownIcon = (name:string) => (
  <MaterialCommunityIcons
    name={name}
    size={50}
    color={theme.colors.text}
  />
);
```

Then I should pass the above component as a prop to the following component:

```
const Dropdown = () =>{
  <DropDownPicker
    ArrowDownIconComponent={ArrowDownIcon}
  />
}
```

But it doesn't work, since I should pass the prop of `name` to the `ArrowDownIconComponent`. Can somebody please explain me how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong here, in `DropDownPicker` you just have to render your `ArrowDownIconComponent`

```
const DropDownPicker = ({ArrowDownIconComponent}) => (
  ...
  <ArrowDownIconComponent />
  ...
)
```

You can also use it this way

```
const Dropdown = () =>{
  <DropDownPicker
    arrowDownIconComponent={<ArrowDownIconComponent />}
  />
}


const DropDownPicker = ({arrowDownIconComponent}) => (
  ...
  { arrowDownIconComponent }
  ...
)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am asking 'how can I pass the prop `name` to 'ArrowDownIcon' in `ArrowDownIconComponent={ArrowDownIcon}`.

Comment: OK, so second option with `arrowDownIconComponent={<ArrowDownIconComponent name={...} />}`

Comment: yes, unfortunately the problem is it does not work.

Comment: No reason it doesn't work. Why do you have when you `console.log(props.name)` in `ArrowDownIconComponent` ?

Comment: (property) ArrowDownIconComponent: JSX.Element
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(props: { style: StyleProp<ViewStyle>; }) => Element'.
  Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' provides no match for the signature '(props: { style: StyleProp<ViewStyle>; }): Element'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(223, 5): The expected type comes from property 'ArrowDownIconComponent' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DropDownPickerProps<string>'

Comment: Above is the error I get when I change the code to `arrowDownIconComponent={<ArrowDownIcon name={...} />}`

Comment: So it's a type error from your ts definition :)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the name as a prop in this way

```
<DropDownPicker
   ...
   ArrowDownIconComponent={() => <ArrowDownIconComponent name="box" />}
   ...
/>
```

Comment: Sorry this does not work

Comment: are you getting a question mark instead of the icon after making this change? please provide info

Comment: noo, it does give the es-lint error: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unstable-nested-components.md#prevent-creating-unstable-components-inside-components-reactno-unstable-nested-components

Comment: saying that we can't use nested components